# Bind RelayCommand to Button Click or CodeBehind

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, relaycommand, frameworkelement

i want bind RelayCommand to Button Click event 
 (i know i can bind to command property but i want bind to click event)

how i can do this? 
i used this code but not work:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { 
FrameworkElement fe=sender as FrameworkElement;
((FirstViewModel)fe.DataContext).ShowSecondViewCommand();     
}
```

Some of my personal controls do not have this property (command) so i cant bind my commands to command property

Comment: Do you mean call the button command from the click event? Or bind a command to the button from the click event?

Comment: yes call the button command from the click event

Comment: i can show usercontrols with mvvm pattern and each usercontrol can load another usercontrol but  this only work if i bind command! is there any way to do this with codebehind? because i want check user login and after that load another usercontrol

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the correct xaml to bind a command. The following code will execute the command assigned to the button:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { 
    var button = sender as Button;
    if(button.Command != null){
        button.Command.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `InvokeCommandAction` class to do this, or the `EventToCommand` class from MVVMLight

```
<Button xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=SomeCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Honestly though, this is not best practice. Is it not possible for your controls to simply expose a Command property instead?